# list with background and float 'li'

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Homepage</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    background: #000000;
    width: 984px;
}

#menu li {
    float: right;
    background: url('../images/menu_button.png');
    width: 166px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
}
```

It's horizontal menu as you can see (homepage | contact | about us).

But the `#menu` background (#000000) is not displayed (because of the float in the `li` tag).
What can I do? I guess to insert `clear: both` somewhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `overflow:hidden` for your `#menu`, in this way you will clear the float.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gRwBX/

Comment: I was going to post the same thing. `#menu` is collapsing because all of its children are floated, so it has no height. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#menu` will make it expand to the height of its children.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a number of ways to fix your problem:

1. use `:after` pseudo-class (recommend)
   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timezhong/bjcuA/
2. use `float` (common)
   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timezhong/SbLM2/
3. use a combination of `width` and `overflow:hidden` (common)
4. use a `<br />` (not recommend)
5. use a empty `div` with `div#clear {clear:both}` as it's styling (not recommend)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will solve your problem:

```
#menu {  
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;  
color: white;  
min-height: 50px;  
width: 984px;  }
```

**EDIT:**
If a varying height is the case then you should set `min-height` rather than `height`, and it will work like a charm.

Comment: Thank you, but the height is changed anytime.. so I can't add an height parameter.